# AngularJS variable not showing in ng-template

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-template

I've spent hours and hours trying to fix this problem while searching through Google, but I've come up with nothing.

I'm trying to do something relatively simple; when the user clicks on an image, a modal should appear with that image in it.

However, the image does not show up. I can access `{{$ctrl.selectedPhoto.photoname}}` on other parts of the page, but not from within the ng-template. Here's a link to the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/3IoK56UdFD5WXDEpAgRb?p=preview

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: <img ng-class="{'no-text': !photo.text}" ng-src="1.jpg" ng-click="$ctrl.open(photo.name)" src="1.jpg"> here in this tag you can pass photo.photoname and bind it inside the modal.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you mean by "bind it inside the modal"?